# Core Data - Strange Exception on merging context from another thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a background task that is fetching a large amount of data, saving it to a core data context, and that context is merged into a context on the main thread.

I have a tableview that is listing this data via `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Occasionally (but very seldom) I'm getting a strange error in this area of the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /* standard uitableview cell stuff */

    PSCourse *course = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = course.name; // <--- EXCEPTION HERE

    return cell;
}
```

I get a stop on the line noted above (via obj-c exception breakpoint).

If I press continue in the debugger, I get this unintelligible error:

> Assertion failed: (_Unwind_SjLj_Resume() can't return), function
>   _Unwind_SjLj_Resume, file
>   /SourceCache/libunwind/libunwind-24.1/src/Unwind-sjlj.c, line 326.

I'm not sure why the app would be crashing on the line above, but perhaps the object in question was removed whilst the tableview was rendering that object.  If this is the case, what should I do?  Should I swallow the error?  Should I be checking the state of the fetched results controller somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove stop on exceptions and see if you can see the real exception?

The cryptic error looks like something in the exception system is failing. "Unwind" = unwind the stack, the general technique for passing execution to exception handlers; "sjlc" = setjump/longjump, the C mechanism for stack unwinding; "resume" = because the debugger stopped it midway?

Anyway, if a change (or deletion) of the object in the background thread is the cause of your problem, maybe you could solve it by locking the persistent store coordinator in cellForRowAtIndexPath. It shouldn't have to wait for the whole background task to finish. Since you're not explicitly locking in the background task (I assume), Core Data will take some more or less intelligent strategy for locking, possibly acquiring and releasing the lock with each operation. So your UI only needs to wait for one operation (possibly one small batch of operations).

It might still really hurt performance, but it doesn't hurt to try it. Even if it makes performance unacceptable, if it fixes your problem you might take that as a confirmation that at least you guessed the cause right.

Comment: If I remove it then I don't get a break on the line in question, but I still get that same unwind error.

Comment: And that locking behavior sounds like it would murder performance.